# Hook to execute after deleting a Custom Taxonomy

Tags: plugin-development

I need to execute a portion of code after each: Add / Edit / delete a custom taxonomy .
For creation / edition it works well, but for deletion non :

```
    add_action( 'edited_product_category', array ( $this , 'term_edit_success' ), 10, 2 );
    add_action( 'create_product_category', array ( $this , 'term_create_success' ), 10, 2 );
    add_action( 'delete_product_category', array ( $this , 'term_delete_success' ), 10, 2 );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the hook to this  :

```
add_action( 'delete_term_taxonomy', array ( $this , 'term_delete_success' ), 9, 1 );
```

it resolved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
Changes argument numbers 2 to 4 as below

add_action( 'delete_product_category', array ( $this , 'term_delete_success' ), 10, 4);
```

Here is the reference function.

You may find detail on wordpress codex

[More info](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/delete_taxonomy/)

```
do_action( "delete_{$taxonomy}", int $term, int $tt_id, mixed $deleted_term, array $object_ids )
```